# ActiveMQ delete destination before publish

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

why this rout throws exceprion and how i can solve that problem?
Producer:

```
 from("rmi:endpoint").
.setHeader(JmsHeaders.DELIVERY_MODE, constant("PERSISTENT"))
.to(ExchangePattern.InOut, "activemq:myQueue?requestTimeout=86400000");
```

Consumer:

```
from("activemq:myQueue").to("http://....")
```

Exception:

```
org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: org.springframework.jms.InvalidDestinationException: Cannot publish to a deleted Destination: temp-queue://ID:stws2503-55943-1497338780769-6:1:1
```

Update:

```
        <artifactId>activemq-broker</artifactId>
        <version>5.14.5</version>
```

add param

```
broker.url=tcp://localhost:61616?transport.useInactivityMonitor=false
```

exception is still thrown

**Problem found:**

Problem in **temp-queue**,becouse it in-memory and after restarting server destination not exist, how i can avoid this problem? any ideas ??

I try to change `setUseTempMirroredQueues(false)` and `broker.setCacheTempDestinations(false)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved. Im just added params `replyToType=Exclusive` and `replyTo`